# Regex: how to remove redundant substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a string. There is redundant text at the end of this string. I want to remove all of that redundant text (both the first and second instance of the redundant text). How can I find all the repeated text at the end of a string and remove it?

In my example, I am working with a string that also has a prefix that I'm removing. So for example, I want: `prefix a b c d e 123 d e 123` to return `a b c`

The duplicate substring can vary in length. So I would want: `prefix a b c 123 c 123` to return `a b`

I tried matching this with

```
import re
re.sub(
    r'prefix ([a-z ]*)\2([a-z ]* \d*)$',
    r'\1',
    'prefix a b c 123 c 123'
)
```

but of course this led to a forwards reference error since I'm referring to the contents of \2 before I've created it.

I'm doing this regex in Python. 3.7.

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r'prefix ([a-z ]*)([a-z ]* \d*)\2*$', r'\1', text)`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VAok3G/1). Or, `prefix ([a-z ]*)([a-z ]* \d*)\2+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for search:

```sh
^prefix\s+(.*?)(.+?)\2+$
```

and use: `r'\1'` for replacement.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R8AEh3/1)

**Python Code:**

```
import re

r = re.sub(
    r'^prefix\s+(.*?)(.+?)\2+$',
    r'\1',
    'prefix a b c 123 c 123'
)
print (r)
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/4v79Av)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `prefix\s+`: Match text `prefix` followed by 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)`: Match 0 or more of any characters in capture group #1
- `(.+?)`; Match 1 or more of any characters in capture group #2
- `\2+`: Match 1 or more repetitions of group #2
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern, you can put the `\2` after the second group, before the end of the string.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
prefix ([a-z ]*)([a-z ]* \d*)\2$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/axCb9h/1)

```
import re
result = re.sub(
    r'prefix ([a-z ]*)([a-z ]* \d*)\2$',
    r'\1',
    'prefix a b c 123 c 123'
)
print(result)
```

Output

```
a b
```